# Azure Synapse connection to private container in Blob store is not working

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am following the steps from this guide to connect to my Blob store which is General purpose V2 (Not ADL Gen 2): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python

My linked service to blob storage account was using managed identity and it works just fine for public access container for reading files with this syntax

```
blob_sas_token = mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(linked_service_name)
wasb_path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, blob_relative_path)

spark.conf.set('fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name), blob_sas_token)
df = spark.read.option('multiline','true').json(wasb_path)
```

But when I try to connect to a private access container using similar method, it gives me Path does not exist error.

I cannot change the access level of container since it is production system.

I tried to create a linkedserver with SAS key at account level and usedsame syntax just to see if it works, but I get

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds.
: java.lang.Exception: Access token couldn't be obtained {"result":"DependencyError","errorId":"BadRequest","errorMessage":"LSRServiceException is [{\"StatusCode\":400,\"ErrorResponse\":{\"code\":\"SasTokenNull\",\"message\":\"SAS token is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck the path of your blob file and roles for the managed identity. If you still face the same, you can use the **linked service for blob storage with account key authentication** as a workaround.

These are my private containers.
[image]

CSV file inside the container3

[image]

Here, when creating the linked service for the Blob storage **select the Account key as the Authentication type** and give your subscription and storage account details.

[image]

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

blob_account_name = 'storage account name'
blob_container_name = 'container name' 
blob_relative_path = 'blob folder path' 
linked_service_name ='linked service name' 

blob_sas_token = mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(linked_service_name)
wasb_path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, blob_relative_path)
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name), blob_sas_token)
df=spark.read.csv(wasb_path)
df.show()
```

Here I am using the same code from the [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python#configure-access-to-azure-blob-storage) that you provided.

**Output:**
[image]